# Writing in binary files C programming with spaces

Tags: c, string, file, io, whitespace

I want to write three names on one row in binary file. How to do this? For example:
Ivan Petrov Petrov.
If i write

```
char name[50];
int sizeName;
FILE*fp;
    if((fp=fopen("clients.bin","ab+"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening the file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Enter client's name: \n");
    scanf("%s",name);
sizeName=strlen(name);
fwrite(&sizeName,sizeof(int),1,fp);
fwrite(name,sizeName,1,fp);
```

In this way i can only write Ivan in file, but i want all 3 words ? How to do it@

Comment: `scanf()` taken input untill it encounters a space. For strings with space, use `fgets()` to read them.

Comment: Use `fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin);` or `scanf("%49[^\n]%*c", name);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the way that you read the input. [`scanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) will stop as soon as it meets a whitespace. As a result `name` will store only "Ivan". [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) can come in handy here.

Change this:

```
scanf("%s",name);
```

to this:

```
fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin); // read the line (including the newline from the user's enter hit
name[strlen(name) - 1] = '\0';    // overwrite the newline
```

and you should get this:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c 
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
Enter client's name: 
Ivan Petrov Petrov
Ivan Petrov Petrov
```

after printing your string like this `printf("%s\n", name);`.